# How do I solve this BROKEN PACKAGE PROBLEM?

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies

```
krishna@Krishna-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.10:
 python3.10 depends on libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2); however:
  Version of libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 on system is 3.10.4-1+focal1.

dpkg: error processing package python3.10 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.10-minimal:
 python3.10-minimal depends on libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2); however:
  Version of libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 on system is 3.10.4-1+focal1.

dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.10
 python3.10-minimal
```

AND WHEN I TRY TO "SUDO APT --FIX-BROKEN INSTALL"

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 204340 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.
deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is als
o in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64
.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-stdli
b:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Have any PPAs been added to your software sources?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you running? No current version uses  python 3.10

Comment: please avoid gratuitous use of capital letters. It adds nothing to your question and can be regarded as shouting and there rude.

Answer (score 2):

A crude solution would be to force an overwrite.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken -o DPkg::Options::=--force-overwrite install
```

Similar as @Whippy 's answer, but you don't need to find and specify the debs.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. The answer is in the link provided by @karel  but the exact step I took was:

```
~ $ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
```

This reduces the overwrite error to a warning and completes the install of the package.

After this you can 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' to complete the upgrades successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This issue already fixed in [github of the Deadsnakes PPA's](https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/207)

```
sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.10' | awk '{print $2}')
```

or

```
sudo apt purge libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev python3.10 python3.10-minimal python3.10-dev python3.10-venv
sudo apt install python3.10
```

Hope this helps.