# Problem updating 20.04 - python3.7 errors

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3

I am just trying to run my normal update/upgrade and have been getting this error:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.7-minimal:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 141307 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.13-1+focal3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.13-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to google and look here and the solutions I have found that are recent are not working.  Attempting to run Broken Fix results in:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.13-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Python 3.7 is not the standard version on 20.04 (the standard is Python 3.8). So why do you have 3.7 installed in the first place?

Comment: I have the same error, and I have Python 3.7 because certain machine learning libraries are not supported under 3.8 (that's the reason for Python 3.7 on my machine at least).

Comment: UPDATE: For the time being, I was able to allow system upgrades by manually removing all the packages that gave me errors ("sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq [package name]"). However, I would seek additional advice before doing that. I just took a risk and did this because I personally found no better solutions and needed to upgrade my system, which was being blocked by this problem.

Comment: Thank you the "sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq xxxxx" allowed me to get past this problem.  I am really not sure why that version of Python was on this server.  I run almost everything on this server in docker as containers.  I was able to resume running updates to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 17):

I fixed it by removing python3.7 and its library and reinstalling it after.

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3.7 
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpython3.7-stdlib 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Comment: What worked for me, in the end, was including the other packages that faced dependency problems in the same `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq` command, as well as doing `sudo apt-get remove --purge *python3.7*` from https://askubuntu.com/a/1417603/955443 before reinstalling python

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous answers worked for me, so I made I work with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge *python3.7*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install python3.7-full
```

This was in the context of using Python from the `deadsnakes` repository.

Answer (score 1):

Remove and Reinstalling python 3.7 works for me

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3.7 
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpython3.7-stdlib 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use Anaconda/Miniconda for non-administrative uses. You may also compile python from the source in your home folder.

```bsh
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
tar -xf Python-2.7.18.tgz

cd Python-2.7.18/

./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME/local
 make -j4
 make install
```

To use this installation add these lines into $HOME/.bashrc and source it.

```bsh
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib
export MANPATH=$HOME/local/share/man
```

Since different projects often use conflicting packages you may use different conda environments or use venv with your local installation

```bsh
python -m venv <project_name>_env
```

This activate this environment use

```bsh
. <project_name>_env/bin/activate
```

and

```bsh
deactivate
```

to come out.