# Ubuntu 20.04 Uninstalled python and now PC won't start

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

let me put you in some context.
I recently started a job as backend developer and we're working with docker and one of the images has python version 3.8.3

I was configuring things with the other (and only) backend guy from the company who practically did everything on the app until now. He told me I needed python version 3.8.3 in a virtualenv to make the docker image run locally so I can test the code I write.

So we started messing with python versions, downloaded the 8.3 version and installed it through a makefile, but the virtualenv was still taking the 8.10

We ran out of time and called it a day, hours later I get home and the terminal won't open, so I investigated a bit and it was about the pythong mess up we did earlier. Some people recommended uninstalling certain version of python which I did.

I opened the tty console and checked all my python versions, it showed python3 and python3.8 so I went ahead and removed the 3.8 and rebooted my PC.

It is now stuck in a black screen with this message:

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 360061/61022208 files, 9747664/244059136 blocks
```

And a simple text input prompt that won't do anything.

Can somebody help, or should I just format the entire thing?

Comment: you can try to boot into a live USB, chroot into your main install and reinstall python3.8. `python3` might actually be a symlink to python 3.8, so now you have no python and the system requires it

Comment: I recommend you to install a local version of python in your home folder upon fixing this issue, you may use these steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1408119/1107236