# Tinkering with installed python version cause issues

Tags: python

People with specific needs often install a particular version of python for their needs, such as

[Problem updating 20.04 - python3.7 errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405480/problem-updating-20-04-python3-7-errors)

and

[Ubuntu 20.04 Uninstalled python and now PC won't start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407658/ubuntu-20-04-uninstalled-python-and-now-pc-wont-start)

What are the ways to install a different python version on a system so the system does not crash?

Comment: You can install all kinds of python versions, but don't change default version. As simple as that.

Comment: And also don't go around doing `sudo pip install`.