# error update casper

Tags: apt, system-installation

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  casper
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 181 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/52.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 352376 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../casper_1.470_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking casper (1.470) over (1.465) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/casper_1.470_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-premount/20iso_scan', which is also in package lupin-casper 0.57build1
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/casper_1.470_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: As written, this isn't really a question. Please edit your post to add some context - explain what you are trying to do, what version of Ubuntu you are using, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not really a question, but the problem is clear and seems to be something bigger. I got the same while trying to update from Mint 20.3 to Mint 21. Reinstallation helped.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall / Remove casper package

In this section, we are going to explain the necessary steps to uninstall casper package:

sudo apt remove casper

sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove

Then reinstall it

sudo apt update

sudo apt install casper

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this on terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/casper_1.470_amd64.deb
```

And... this is my screenshot:

[Casper error solve in Upgrading linuxmint (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1H3.png)

And this is worked in my Linux Mint