# Installing NodeJs on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, nodejs

I cannot get this thing to work.
I was following these instructions from digitalocean:

[How To Install Node.js on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Then, I am getting this error messages:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 179 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 332991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_18.7.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (18.7.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.7.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.7.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I found this article:

[Upgrading nodejs on Ubuntu: How to fix broken pipe error?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627635/upgrading-nodejs-on-ubuntu-how-to-fix-broken-pipe-error)

But its an older version of Ubuntu. I need some help to perform this project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in). Perhaps you did not clean up some previous attempt to install Node, and the remainders of that attempt is blocking your current attempt. Many people make that mistake once.

Comment: @user535733 `sudo apt remove nodejs npm` does not uninstall the older versions of nodejs? Should I run `sudo apt purge nodejs*` and `sudo apt purge npm*`

Comment: @user535733 wouldnt force `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <file-path>` break my system? in my case `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp`

Comment: You don't need to purge using wildcards (that's *dangerous*!). Your output clearly tells you exactly which package needs to be removed. It's possible that --force-overwrite might break your system. You should read the other answers, too, before making a decision.

Comment: @user535733 I have tried overwrite and this what I get:

Comment: `krillavilla@OMEN:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
dpkg-deb: error: '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp`

Comment: That output is expected, since your command was very wrong. DON'T leap to try the first thing you read -- that's how folks break their systems. This is NOT the kind of problem amenable to a magic incantation. It's actually very simple if you take a few minutes and *understand* the problem.

Comment: @user535733 I apology for rushing. I just want to get this project out the way.

Comment: I got confliced packages coming from `libnode72` which was older version amd64:12.22. I had to remove it first before installing Nodjs newer version

Comment: Hooray! You got it! Well done.