# answers Error while installing new packages in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Solved: [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

i tried once to reinstall and install mongod and mongodb, after that my ubuntu system became very low, now in each time i try to install a new package, i got this error, i tried to do sudo apt --fix-broken install but i got errors too bcz of mongodb package

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.20.3-1ubuntu2).
wget set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: gcc (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libbz2-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                       libc-dev
              Recommends: bzip2-doc but it is not going to be installed
 libgdbm-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                        libc-dev
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libncurses-dev (= 6.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnss3-dev : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.8) but 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
               Depends: libnspr4-dev (>= 4.6.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreadline-dev : Depends: libncurses-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.3) but 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12 is to be installed
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                       libc-dev
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

after i run this sudo apt --fix-broken install i got :

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libtcmalloc-minimal4 libxau-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev
  libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libyaml-cpp0.6 mongo-tools mongodb-server-core
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 248 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/92.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 187 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 190222 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_5.0.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (5.0.11) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.11
_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (5.0.11) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.11
_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.6.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.6.0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_10
0.6.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3
.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.11_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.11_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.6.0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

after i run this sudo apt update i get :

```
Hit:1 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:3 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease      
Hit:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release        
Get:8 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:9 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [941 kB]
Get:10 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [688 kB]
Fetched 1,964 kB in 9s (215 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
248 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

after i run this sudo apt upgrade i get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when i run this sudo apt list --upgradable i get :

```
Listing... Done
alsa-ucm-conf/focal-updates,focal-updates 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.13 all [upgradable from: 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.11]
apport-gtk/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24 all [upgradable from: 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21]
apport/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.24 all [upgradable from: 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21]
apt-transport-https/focal-updates,focal-updates 2.0.9 all [upgradable from: 2.0.6]
apt-utils/focal-updates 2.0.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.6]
apt/focal-updates 2.0.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.6]
bash/focal-updates,focal-security 5.0-6ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0-6ubuntu1.1]
bluez-cups/focal-updates,focal-security 5.53-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.53-0ubuntu3.5]
bluez-obexd/focal-updates,focal-security 5.53-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.53-0ubuntu3.5]
bluez/focal-updates,focal-security 5.53-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.53-0ubuntu3.5]
bolt/focal-updates 0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.8-4ubuntu1]
ca-certificates/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 20211016~20.04.1 all [upgradable from: 20210119~20.04.2]
command-not-found/focal-updates,focal-updates 20.04.6 all [upgradable from: 20.04.5]
containerd.io/focal 1.6.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.5.10-1]
cups-bsd/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-client/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 all [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-core-drivers/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-daemon/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-ipp-utils/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-ppdc/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups-server-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 all [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
cups/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
curl/focal-updates,focal-security 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7]
dbus-user-session/focal-updates,focal-security 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1]
dbus-x11/focal-updates,focal-security 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1]
dbus/focal-updates,focal-security 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1]
dirmngr/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
distro-info-data/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 0.43ubuntu1.10 all [upgradable from: 0.43ubuntu1.9]
dnsmasq-base/focal-updates,focal-security 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.4]
docker-ce-cli/focal 5:22.06.0~beta.0-0~ubuntu.20.04.0~focal amd64 [upgradable from: 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal]
docker-ce-rootless-extras/focal 5:22.06.0~beta.0-0~ubuntu.20.04.0~focal amd64 [upgradable from: 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal]
docker-ce/focal 5:22.06.0~beta.0-0~ubuntu.20.04.0~focal amd64 [upgradable from: 5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal]
dpkg/focal-updates,focal-security 1.19.7ubuntu3.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.19.7ubuntu3]
e2fsprogs/focal-updates,focal-security 1.45.5-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.45.5-2ubuntu1]
firefox-locale-en/focal-updates,focal-security 103.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 98.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
firefox/focal-updates,focal-security 103.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 98.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
fwupd-signed/focal-updates 1.27.1ubuntu7+1.2-2~20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.27.1ubuntu5+1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
fwupd/focal-updates 1.7.5-3~20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0/focal-updates,focal-security 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2]
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-2]
gir1.2-gtk-3.0/focal-updates 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.24.20-0ubuntu1]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/focal-updates,focal-security 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0/focal-updates,focal-security 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
git-man/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.5 all [upgradable from: 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2]
git/focal-updates,focal-security 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2]
gnome-control-center-data/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 all [upgradable from: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu3]
gnome-control-center-faces/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 all [upgradable from: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu3]
gnome-control-center/focal-updates 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu3]
gnupg-l10n/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 all [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gnupg-utils/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gnupg/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 all [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpg-agent/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpg-wks-client/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpg-wks-server/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpg/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpgconf/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpgsm/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
gpgv/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1]
grub-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.13]
grub-pc-bin/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.13]
grub-pc/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.13]
grub2-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.13]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gstreamer1.0-gl/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gstreamer1.0-gtk3/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/focal-updates 1.16.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1]
gstreamer1.0-tools/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-2]
gstreamer1.0-x/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
gtk-update-icon-cache/focal-updates 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.24.20-0ubuntu1]
gvfs-backends/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs-bin/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs-common/focal-updates,focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 all [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs-daemons/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs-fuse/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs-libs/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gvfs/focal-updates 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1]
gzip/focal-updates,focal-security 1.10-0ubuntu4.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.10-0ubuntu4]
iio-sensor-proxy/focal-updates 2.8-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.8-1ubuntu1]
intel-microcode/focal-updates,focal-security 3.20220510.0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20210608.0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
isc-dhcp-client/focal-updates 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2]
isc-dhcp-common/focal-updates 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2]
klibc-utils/focal-updates,focal-security 2.0.7-1ubuntu5.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.7-1ubuntu5]
kmod/focal-updates 27-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27-1ubuntu2]
language-pack-gnome-en-base/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:20.04+20220211 all [upgradable from: 1:20.04+20210802]
language-pack-gnome-en/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:20.04+20220211 all [upgradable from: 1:20.04+20210802]
libapt-pkg6.0/focal-updates 2.0.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.6]
libarchive13/focal-updates,focal-security 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1]
libavcodec58/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libavfilter7/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libavformat58/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libavutil56/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libbluetooth3/focal-updates,focal-security 5.53-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.53-0ubuntu3.5]
libc-bin/focal-updates 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.31-0ubuntu9.7]
libcom-err2/focal-updates,focal-security 1.45.5-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.45.5-2ubuntu1]
libcups2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
libcupsimage2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1]
libcurl3-gnutls/focal-updates,focal-security 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7]
libcurl4/focal-updates,focal-security 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7]
libdbus-1-3/focal-updates,focal-security 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1]
libdpkg-perl/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 1.19.7ubuntu3.2 all [upgradable from: 1.19.7ubuntu3]
libevdev2/focal-updates,focal-security 1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1]
libexempi8/focal-updates,focal-security 2.5.1-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.5.1-1build1]
libext2fs2/focal-updates,focal-security 1.45.5-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.45.5-2ubuntu1]
libfprint-2-2/focal-updates 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.6]
libfprint-2-tod1/focal-updates 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.6]
libfreerdp-client2-2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libfreerdp2-2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libfreetype6/focal-updates,focal-security 2.10.1-2ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1]
libfribidi0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.0.8-2ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.8-2]
libfwupd2/focal-updates 1.7.5-3~20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin/focal-updates,focal-security 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.3 all [upgradable from: 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2]
libgnutls30/focal-updates,focal-security 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.6]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/focal-updates 1.16.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1]
libgstreamer1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.3-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-2]
libgtk-3-0/focal-updates 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.24.20-0ubuntu1]
libgtk-3-bin/focal-updates 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.24.20-0ubuntu1]
libgtk-3-common/focal-updates,focal-updates 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 all [upgradable from: 3.24.20-0ubuntu1]
libharfbuzz-icu0/focal-updates,focal-security 2.6.4-1ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.6.4-1ubuntu4]
libharfbuzz0b/focal-updates,focal-security 2.6.4-1ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.6.4-1ubuntu4]
libhttp-daemon-perl/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 6.06-1ubuntu0.1 all [upgradable from: 6.06-1]
libinput-bin/focal-updates,focal-security 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2]
libinput10/focal-updates,focal-security 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/focal-updates,focal-security 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
libjcat1/focal-updates 0.1.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.1.3-2~ubuntu20.04.1]
libkeyutils1/focal-updates 1.6-6ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.6-6ubuntu1]
libklibc/focal-updates,focal-security 2.0.7-1ubuntu5.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.7-1ubuntu5]
libkmod2/focal-updates 27-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27-1ubuntu2]
libldap-2.4-2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8]
libldap-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9 all [upgradable from: 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8]
libldb2/focal-updates,focal-security 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
liblouis-data/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 3.12.0-3ubuntu0.1 all [upgradable from: 3.12.0-3]
liblouis20/focal-updates,focal-security 3.12.0-3ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.12.0-3]
liblzma5/focal-updates,focal-security 5.2.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.2.4-1ubuntu1]
libmbim-glib4/focal-updates 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.24.8-1~20.04]
libmbim-proxy/focal-updates 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.24.8-1~20.04]
libmm-glib0/focal-updates 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.6-2~20.04.1]
libmysqlclient21/focal-updates,focal-security 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
libnetplan0/focal-updates 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.5]
libnss-systemd/focal-updates 245.4-4ubuntu3.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.15]
libnss3/focal-updates,focal-security 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6]
libntfs-3g883/focal-updates,focal-security 1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.1]
libpam-systemd/focal-updates 245.4-4ubuntu3.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.15]
libpcre3/focal-updates,focal-security 2:8.39-12ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.39-12build1]
libpcrecpp0v5/focal-updates,focal-security 2:8.39-12ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.39-12build1]
libpostproc55/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libpq5/focal-updates,focal-security 12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
libpython3.8-minimal/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
libpython3.8-stdlib/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
libpython3.8/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2]
libqmi-glib5/focal-updates 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.28.6-1~20.04.1]
libqmi-proxy/focal-updates 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.28.6-1~20.04.1]
libsensors-config/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1 all [upgradable from: 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1]
libsensors5/focal-updates 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1]
libsepol1/focal-updates,focal-security 3.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0-1]
libsmbclient/focal-updates,focal-security 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.1]
libsnmp-base/focal-updates,focal-updates 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5 all [upgradable from: 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3]
libsnmp35/focal-updates 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3]
libsqlite3-0/focal-updates,focal-security 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2]
libss2/focal-updates,focal-security 1.45.5-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.45.5-2ubuntu1]
libssl1.1/focal-updates,focal-security 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12]
libswresample3/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libswscale5/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]
libsystemd0/focal-updates 245.4-4ubuntu3.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.15]
libtiff5/focal-updates,focal-security 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libudev1/focal-updates 245.4-4ubuntu3.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.15]
libwbclient0/focal-updates,focal-security 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.1]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/focal-updates,focal-security 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
libwinpr2-2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.0+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libxml2/focal-updates,focal-security 2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libxslt1.1/focal-updates,focal-security 1.1.34-4ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.34-4]
linux-firmware/focal-updates,focal-updates 1.187.33 all [upgradable from: 1.187.26]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22]
locales/focal-updates,focal-updates 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 all [upgradable from: 2.31-0ubuntu9.7]
login/focal-updates 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.1]
logsave/focal-updates,focal-security 1.45.5-2ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.45.5-2ubuntu1]
modemmanager/focal-updates 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.6-2~20.04.1]
mongodb-mongosh/focal 1.5.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.3.1]
mongodb-org-database-tools-extra/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]
mongodb-org-database/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]
mongodb-org-shell/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]
mongodb-org-tools/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]
mongodb-org/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]
netplan.io/focal-updates 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.5]
networkd-dispatcher/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.3 all [upgradable from: 2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1]
ntfs-3g/focal-updates,focal-security 1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.1]
openssh-client/focal-updates 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4]
openssl/focal-updates,focal-security 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12]
```

Comment: @Nmath i'm trying to install python so i run this
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev

Comment: @Nmath i did what you asked for sir

Comment: @Nmath, it still giving me errors,

Comment: i run sudo apt list --upgradable , and i past the result above @Nmath

Comment: Do you have a backup of your database? You may want to run `sudo apt remove mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-tools` and get rid of these packages. Then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` again until your system is up-to-date. Only then should you try to add anything new.

Comment: @Nmath when i run 
sudo apt remove mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-tools

 i got this : 

``` 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove mongo-tools mongodb-server-core`

Comment: @Nmath the same i'm getting : 
```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution
```

Comment: Hmmm do you remember exactly what mongodb packages you installed? Those are the ones I would try to remove. You may have success with `sudo apt autoremove`. Unfortunately things can get very messy when you try to install new software when your system is very outdated. Look up "dependency hell" -- that's the situation going on with your system at the moment

Comment: @Nmath
```
mongod --version
db version v3.6.8
git version: 8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: @Nmath those one : 

mongodb-mongosh/focal 1.5.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.3.1]

mongodb-org-database-tools-extra/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]

mongodb-org-database/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]

mongodb-org-shell/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]

mongodb-org-tools/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]

mongodb-org/focal 5.0.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6]

netplan.io/focal-updates 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.5]

Comment: `sudo apt remove` whatever packages you indicated when you originally installed the software prior to updating your system

Comment: @Nmath doesn't work :/ i need to delete the entire system and reinstall it

Comment: Not necessarily, but that is an option if you just want a clean slate and don't want to waste any more time trying to untangle this particular issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in). This occurs most commonly when folks try multiple ways of installing without cleaning up between attempts.

Comment: @user535733 thank you so much i really appreciate it thank you, it worked for me, you saved me