# libgl1-mesa-drv won't update from Discover on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 22.04 and I recently received an error in relation to updating libgl1-mesa-drv via the Discover software center.

The error message is the following:

```
Package failed to install:
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite &apos;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so&apos;, which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri
```

The system I am running is the following:

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
  KDE Plasma version: 5.24.6
  KDE Frameworks version: 5.92.0
  Qt Version: 5.15.3
  Kernel Version: 5.15.0-48-generic (64-bit)
  Graphics platform: X11
  Processor: 8 × Intel Core i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
  Memory: 15.5 GB of RAM
  Graphics processor: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error trying to override /use/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml which is also in libgranite-common](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432311/dpkg-error-trying-to-override-use-share-metainfo-granite-appdata-xml-which-is-a)

Comment: Not really - I cannot seem to update this file and am unsure why. Sorry I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and want to move away from WIndows.

Comment: I tried following your advice with the following in the terminal and got this:

Comment: ..
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.1+git2210121823.d9f989928a6~j~mesarc1) over (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.1+git2210121823.d9f989928a6~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.1+git2210121823.d9f989928a6~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `sudo dpkg --dry-run -P libgl1-amber-dri` please, this is only a simulation. 2 Packages are containing the same file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so'` package `package libgl1-amber-dri` and `libgl1-mesa-dri` Thats why you have the problem,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)