# Package System is Borken

Tags: package-management, upgrade, software-installation, updates, dpkg

I'm currently running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with livepatch and Pro on and my package manager is broken.

[image: package broken]

I've had an issue with my package system for a few weeks now. I think it may have started when I tried to install wine but I don't see any issues relating to that attempt from the error output.
Regardless attempting to run an update with updater results with this:

I've removed all third party package sources as well as all "Other Software" sources in Updater so update runs fine and returns with:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease 
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
22 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Upgrade obviously doesn't work and results in an unmet dependency for gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : 
Depends: libldacbt-enc2 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Same with -f flags and running 'apt --fix-broken install' gives a similar error:

```
Unpacking libldacbt-enc2:amd64 (2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libldacbt-enc2_2.0.2.3+gi t20200429+ed310a0-4_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldacBT_enc.so.2', which is al so in package libldac:amd64 2.0.2.3~r26478861 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libldacbt-enc2_2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried deleting the contents of the archive: /var/cache/apt/archives/libldacbt-enc2_2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4_amd64.deb as recommended elsewhere to no avail as fix broken install yields the same error as before.
Same goes with "dist upgrade"

I've also tried purging gstreamer1.0-plugins bad and libldacbtenc with no results.

I'm using a proprietary NVIDIA driver for my GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile, nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)
trying to change to 530 yields:

```
pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package: trying to overwrite 'usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldacBT_enc.so.2', which is also in package libldac (313) ran apt-clean then update-m and then dpkg
--configure -a gave: 
Errors were encountered while processing: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 pulseeffects
```

then ran sudo apt list --upgradable:

```
Listing... Done apt-transport-https/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.4.9 all [upgradable from: 2.4.8] dnsmasq-base/jammy-updates,jammy-security
2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.2] ipp-usb/jammy-updates,jammy-security 0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.9.20-1] libglib2.0-0/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1] libglib2.0-0/jammy-updates
2.72.4-0ubuntu2 i386 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1] libglib2.0-bin/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from:
2.72.4-0ubuntu1] libglib2.0-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 all [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1] libssl3/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8] libssl3/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 i386 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8] linux-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security
5.15.0.71.69 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.69.67] linux-headers-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.71.69 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.69.67] linux-image-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.71.69 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0.69.67] linux-libc-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-71.78 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0-69.76] linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security
5.15.0-71.78 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0-69.76+1] openssl/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8] tzdata/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0] ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.14.4~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.13.6~22.04.1] vim-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 all [upgradable from: 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5] vim-runtime/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 all [upgradable from: 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5] vim-tiny/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5] vim/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5] xxd/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5] then apt upgrade -f: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done Calculating upgrade... Done Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled: libimage-magick-perl imagemagick libjs-jquery-ui libavdevice58 ffmpeg libopenexr25 libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libavcodec-extra58 libpython2.7 libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common libavformat58 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libavfilter7 Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro The following NEW packages will be installed: libldacbt-enc2 linux-headers-5.15.0-71 linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-71-generic The following packages will be upgraded: apt-transport-https dnsmasq-base ipp-usb libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libssl3 libssl3:i386 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic openssl tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd 22 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed. 15 standard LTS security updates Need to get 193 MB/193 MB of archives. After this operation, 729 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 [80.9 kB] Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libglib2.0-0 i386 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 [1,567 kB] Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 [1,462 kB] Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 [4,968 B] Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libssl3 i386 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 [1,943 kB] Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libssl3 amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 [1,902 kB] Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 [1,185 kB] Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [354 kB] Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.14.4~22.04 [171 kB] Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 [1,728 kB] Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 [707 kB] Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 [6,825 kB] Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 [53.7 kB] Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 [81.5 kB] Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 2.4.9 [1,510 B] Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 dnsmasq-base amd64 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3 [354 kB] Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ipp-usb amd64 0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 [2,017 kB] Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [23.2 MB] Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [11.4 MB] Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [64.3 MB] Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.15.0.71.69 [1,696 B] Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.15.0.71.69 [2,492 B] Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-71 all 5.15.0-71.78 [12.3 MB] Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [2,884 kB] Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.15.0.71.69 [2,346 B] Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [1,323 kB] Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [35.1 kB] Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [56.7 MB] Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [7,022 B] Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic amd64 5.15.0-71.78 [5,354 B] Fetched 193 MB in 36s (5,317 kB/s) Extracting templates from packages: 100% Preconfiguring packages ... (Reading database ... 315821 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../00-libglib2.0-bin_2.72.4-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ... Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) over (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack .../01-libglib2.0-0_2.72.4-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ... De-configuring libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1), to allow configuration of li bglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) ... Unpacking libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) over (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack .../02-libglib2.0-0_2.72.4-0ubuntu2_i386.deb ... Unpacking libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) over (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack .../03-libglib2.0-data_2.72.4-0ubuntu2_all.deb ... Unpacking libglib2.0-data (2.72.4-0ubuntu2) over (2.72.4-0ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack .../04-libldacbt-enc2_2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4_amd64.de b ... Unpacking libldacbt-enc2:amd64 (2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4) ... dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-PANafk/04-libldacbt-enc2_2.
0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldacBT_enc.so.2', which is al so in package libldac:amd64 2.0.2.3~r26478861 Preparing to unpack .../05-libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ... De-configuring libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8), to allow configuration of libssl 3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ... Unpacking libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ... Preparing to unpack .../06-libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_i386.deb ... Unpacking libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ... Preparing to unpack .../07-openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9_amd64.deb ... Unpacking openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) ... Preparing to unpack .../08-tzdata_2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ... Unpacking tzdata (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0) ... Preparing to unpack .../09-ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.14.4~22.04_amd64.deb ... Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.14.4~22.04) over (27.13.6~22.04.1) ... Preparing to unpack .../10-vim_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb ... Unpacking vim (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7) over (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5) ... Preparing to unpack .../11-vim-tiny_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb ... Unpacking vim-tiny (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7) over (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5) ... Preparing to unpack .../12-vim-runtime_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_all.deb ... Unpacking vim-runtime (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7) over (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5) ... Preparing to unpack .../13-xxd_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb ... Unpacking xxd (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7) over (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5) ... Preparing to unpack .../14-vim-common_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_all.deb ... Unpacking vim-common (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7) over (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5) ... Preparing to unpack .../15-apt-transport-https_2.4.9_all.deb ... Unpacking apt-transport-https (2.4.9) over (2.4.8) ... Preparing to unpack .../16-dnsmasq-base_2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ... Unpacking dnsmasq-base (2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3) over (2.86-1.1ubuntu0.2) ... Preparing to unpack .../17-ipp-usb_0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking ipp-usb (0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (0.9.20-1) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic. Preparing to unpack .../18-linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71.78_amd64.de b ... Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic. Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71.78_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic. Preparing to unpack .../20-linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71.78_am d64.deb ... Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Preparing to unpack .../21-linux-generic_5.15.0.71.69_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-generic (5.15.0.71.69) over (5.15.0.69.67) ... Preparing to unpack .../22-linux-image-generic_5.15.0.71.69_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.15.0.71.69) over (5.15.0.69.67) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-71. Preparing to unpack .../23-linux-headers-5.15.0-71_5.15.0-71.78_all.deb ... Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-71 (5.15.0-71.78) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic. Preparing to unpack .../24-linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71.78_amd64.de b ... Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Preparing to unpack .../25-linux-headers-generic_5.15.0.71.69_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.71.69) over (5.15.0.69.67) ... Preparing to unpack .../26-linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-71.78_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78) over (5.15.0-69.76) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-71-generi c. Preparing to unpack .../27-linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71.7 8_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-gener ic. Preparing to unpack .../28-linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71. 78_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-gener ic. Preparing to unpack .../29-linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic_5.15.0-71. 78_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ... Preparing to unpack .../30-linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic_5.15.0-71.78_amd64.d eb ... Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic (5.15.0-71.78) over (5.15.0-69.76+1) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing: /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-PANafk/04-libldacbt-enc2_2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4_am d64.deb
```

My logs only go back to the 7th of this month and don't mention the wine install.

It seems that
Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-60.66)

Prompts the

Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

this is from packagekit role='install-packages'

Basically throws the same error over and over again ever for autoremove, purges etc.

Thank you for reading and I greatly appreciate any advice you may have to offer.

**

### UPDATE

**

here is the output for apt policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:

```
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:
  Installed: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.20.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

trying to autoremove libldacbt-enc2 goes back to the usual loop of saying gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad has unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libldacbt-enc2' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libldacbt-enc2 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so when I try to remove --autoreomve gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad it spits out:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseeffects : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

oddly enough when I type in sudo apt remove  --autoremove gstreamer1.0-  I don't see plugins-bad:

```
gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects      gstreamer1.0-pipewire
gstreamer1.0-alsa                      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects     gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0               gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
gstreamer1.0-gl                        gstreamer1.0-tools
gstreamer1.0-gtk3                      gstreamer1.0-vaapi
gstreamer1.0-libav                     gstreamer1.0-x
gstreamer1.0-packagekit
```

just for posterity here is the output for apt policy libldac (which is a third party version I can't remove either)

```
libldac:
  Installed: 2.0.2.3~r26478861
  Candidate: 2.0.2.3~r26478861
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.2.3~r26478861 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and libldacbtenc2:

```
libldac:
  Installed: 2.0.2.3~r26478861
  Candidate: 2.0.2.3~r26478861
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.2.3~r26478861 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

There is no output for python --version (as I understand python2 has been deprecated)

but I have python3 installed: Python 3.10.6

here is the output for apt policy python3:

```
python3:
  Installed: 3.10.6-1~22.04
  Candidate: 3.10.6-1~22.04
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.6-1~22.04 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.10.4-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Also I have never used synaptic package manager and I can't install it anyway for the above issues. installing anything, updating anything etc raises the unmet dependency flag.

Lastly I've looked into my older logs and there is the first one with an error from updating:

```
Start-Date: 2023-03-28  23:57:46

Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-60.66)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2023-03-28  23:57:51
```

Had to omit the full log due to space

there is a gap from 3/28 to 4/7 which is strange I've never changed anything about how I log to my knowledge. Seems to be an error with the nvidia driver which I've never had before. it's currently back to using the generic xorg driver.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` to your question. At some point, "foreign" packages have been installed on your system. The output of this command may shed some light on the situation. If you purged it successfully though, it may not help. You've tried so much stuff, I'm a bit confused about what the current state of your system is. Another way to look into it is to run synaptic package manager and look at the "origin" and "status" results. But if you don't have it installed already, you can't do that.

Comment: Is it possible you removed all or part of Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error trying to override /use/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml which is also in libgranite-common](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432311/dpkg-error-trying-to-override-use-share-metainfo-granite-appdata-xml-which-is-a)

Comment: apt-policy shows libldac was installed from some source that is not in your package system any more. Either you downloaded it and installed it, or you installed it from a repo that you later removed. The waters here are quite muddy.