# Problem upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I tried to upgrade and while it was doing it it stopped.

I rebooted and then the screen started blinking!!!

Now I tried again to upgrade, but it shows the message:

```
Fatal error: Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/include/dc1394/camera.h', which is also in package libdc1394-22-dev
```

- 5.26.0
- firm 5.99.0
- ot 5.15.6
- Kernel 5.140-1054-oem (64bit)
- AMD Ryzen 7

Comment: If it crashed in the middle of an upgrade there is a very good chance that only a fresh install will work. You of course made a backup of any important data before you started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: i tried to do so but something make it stop. that's how i had that message above

Comment: Now i have Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdc1394-dev_2.2.6-4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)                                                        after trying fix broken install

Comment: Not enough complete troubleshooting data to be answerable, sorry. Suggest reinstalling Ubuntu.