# How to resolve: dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-52WhMe/7-python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb (--unpack)?

Tags: upgrade, python, dpkg

```
Preparing to unpack .../7-python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.10.6-1~22.04) over (3.10.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-52WhMe/7-python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/README', which is also in package python3.11-distutils 3.11.0~rc1-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../8-python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) over (3.10.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-52WhMe/8-python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib2to3/Grammar.txt', which is also in package python3.11-lib2to3 3.11.0~rc1-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../9-python3-tz_2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tz (2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.0) over (2022.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-52WhMe/7-python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-52WhMe/8-python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `cat /var/log/dpkg`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)