# Unable to uninstall podman-docker as it's causing hindrance in docker-ce installation in 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

```
akshitadakahtta-MP-Laptop-18-dixxx1-$ sudo apt-get purge remove podman-docker
Reading package 1ists... Done
Calculating dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run apt Fix-broken install to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies
docker-ce Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
```

```
akshitadakahtta-MP-Laptop-18-dixxx1-$ sudo apt fix-broken install   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done
Use sudo apt autoremove to remove them.   
The following additional packages will be installed: docker-ce-cli
The following NEW packages will be installed:
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 191 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed. 0 
Need to get 0 8/13.3 MB of archives.
Errors were encountered while processing:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt fix-broken install with no packages (or specify a solution). 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: bridge-utils ubuntu-fan docker-ce-cli 
After this operation, 36.5 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
(Reading database... 
168500 Files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack... 
/docker-ce-cli 5N3824.0.2-1-ubuntu. 22.04-Jammy and64.deb... 
Unpacking docker-ce-cli (5:24.0.2-1-ubuntu.22.04-Jammy)... dpkgs error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/docker.ce-cli 5x3824.0.2-1-ubuntu.22.04-Jammy amd64.deb (unpack): 
trying to overwrite /usr/bin/docker', which is also in package podman-docker 3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1 
dpkg-debi rrari paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
/var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce-cli 53824.0.2-1-ubuntu-22.04-jammy_amd64.deb 
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/)