# Broken Package Error

Tags: package-management

I'm getting the following:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gir1.2-xapp-1.0: Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.16) but 3.24.37-1ubuntu1 is installed
                 Depends: python3:any but it is a virtual package
```

I tried the broken install but it fails:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxapp-gtk3-module linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
  linux-modules-5.19.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-40-generic
  xapp-sn-watcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxapp1 xapps-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libxapp1 xapps-common
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/185 kB of archives.
After this operation, 216 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 278872 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxapp1_2.6.1+klbklunar_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxapp1:amd64 (2.6.1+klbklunar) over (2.4.2-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libxapp1_2.6.1+klbklunar_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80xapp-gtk3-module', which is also in 
package libxapp-gtk3-module:amd64 2.4.2-3
Preparing to unpack .../xapps-common_2.6.1+klbklunar_all.deb ...
Unpacking xapps-common (2.6.1+klbklunar) over (2.4.2-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xapps-common_2.6.1+klbklu
nar_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/xdg/autostart/xapp-sn-watcher.desktop', which is also
 in package xapp-sn-watcher 2.4.2-3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxapp1_2.6.1+klbklunar_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xapps-common_2.6.1+klbklunar_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libxapp1_2.6.1+klbklunar_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 278872 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxapp1_2.6.1+klbklunar_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxapp1:amd64 (2.6.1+klbklunar) over (2.4.2-3) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80xapp-gtk3-module', which is also in package libxapp-gtk3-module:amd64 2.4.2-3
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libxapp-gtk3-module.so', which is also in package libxapp-gtk3-module:amd64 2.4.2-3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxapp1:amd64:
 libxapp1:amd64 depends on xapps-common (>= 2.6.1+klbklunar); however:
  Version of xapps-common on system is 2.4.2-3.

dpkg: error processing package libxapp1:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.37-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxapp1:amd64
```

I tried to remove libxapp1 but get the same errors. Any ideas? I want to eventually go to 23.10 but can't get past this. I'm on 23.04. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1489330/edit) to add the complete output of `apt policy libxapp1:amd64`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` ?

Comment: Hi! Here's the output:  apt policy libxapp1:amd64
libxapp1:
  Installed: 2.6.1+klbklunar
  Candidate: 2.6.1+klbklunar
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.1+klbklunar 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kelebek333/mint-tools/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.2-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 Packages