# Problem with nvidia package dependencies

Tags: apt, nvidia, dependencies

I have one problem with upgrading of nvidia package. After last updating of this package I faced with such message:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.129.03-0ubuntu1) but 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to solve this problem by this command:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  nvidia-firmware-535-535.129.03
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 61,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 291692 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.129.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-535 (535.129.03-0ubuntu1) over (535.129.03-0ubunt
u0.22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_
535.129.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/nvidia/535.129.03/gsp_ga10x.bin', which is a
lso in package nvidia-firmware-535-535.129.03 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.129.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But it didn't work.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please open up your terminal and try the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.129.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Wish you the very best!

Comment: It has worked!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! But, what was the problem, and why did this fix it?!

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: +1 This saved me a production outage in 1 min v. possibly hours.