# Error during apt upgrade for NodeJS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, nodejs

I encounter this problem while trying to `sudo apt upgrade` my system:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubun
tu3.3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to safely solve this problem?

If this helps, I remember that I installed NodeJS from github (since apt is serving v.12 or something).
I use Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-15-generic x86_64).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it turns out that I have had installed `nodejs` back then which was in conflict with `node`.

`nodejs -v` showed v.12.22.9 and `node -v` was v.20.7.0.

After `sudo apt remove nodejs` it works fine - `sudo apt upgrade` succeded.